# Задачи , построенные с использованием функций С++

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток форумчане ! "Подтолкните" в решении следующих задач , я забуксовал

1. Реализовать функцию, которая принимает массив (плюс его длину) , а также число n , и возвращает индекс числа в массиве или -1 , если такого числа нет.
   Структура : int Search (int a [], const int n, const int key);
2. Реализовать функцию, которая принимает массив и выводит на экран те элементы , значение которых являются простыми числами.
   Структура (IsPrimeNumber) , следовательно я думаю что функция должна выглядеть примерно так:
   primeNumbersInArray (int a[] , const int);
3. Реализовать функцию сортировки массива любым алгоритмом :
   void sortArray (int a[],const int n);

4 Реализовать функцию, которая принимает массив и возвращает индекс его максимального элемента

5 . Аналогично с минимальным элементом.

Р.S. Изучаю С++ не продолжительное время , объяснить решение первых двух задач , остальные похожие думаю я справлюсь , спасибо.

Comment: и на чем же вы сумели забуксовать?

Comment: Да в самом начале на первой задаче , вот я пишу 

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int Search(int a[],const int n,const int key)
{
 void main () 



int i;

  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if ( a[i] == key )
            return i;
    return -1;
}

Счетчик вроде бы правильно создал , а вот, каким образом запустить его в программе вот вопрос.

Comment: @Facktor врать-то зачем, вы же не на экзамене. Этот код написали явно не вы. Почему бы вам не спросить об этом у автора кода?

Comment: Этот пример кода , писал мой преподаватель , не было времени разобраться , за этим пришел к Вам, чтобы объяснили по-человечески , а не ругаться с людьми.

Comment: @Facktor да никто и не хочет с вами ругаться. Просто вы хотите чтобы вам объяснили настолько элементарные вещи, что это вызывает удивление. То, что вы просите вам объяснить - это та простейшая база, которую вы не можете не знать, если прочли хотя бы первые две страницы любой книги по С++. Вряд ли тут есть много желающих делать за вас то, что вы сами сделать почему-то не хотите

Comment: Я не прошу вас решать за меня задачи , я прошу помочь с первой задачей , а конкретно я не могу понять , каким образом вернуть индекс числа (через return) или -1 это работает через if / else ??

P.S. Вопрос : Для чего этот форум создавался чтобы помогать людям не так ли ? А Вы мне говорите в мягкой форме о том что я якобы лентяй , несколько часов сижу уже , может быть Вам это легко , мне не очень.

Comment: @Facktor, это не совсем форум и создавался он для вполне определенного вида помощи (мы же тут не убийства расследуем, правда?) - объяснять людям те или иные вещи, касающиеся программирования. То есть здесь ожидается четко поставленный вопрос или хотя бы та область, про которую надо **рассказать** (Что лучше, А или Б? Я правильно понимаю смысл В? Я делаю Е, но не могу понять Ё, объясните, пожалуйста). Код в ответе может быть, но, в основном, в качестве пояснения.

Возврат значения из функции делается действительно через return. If/elsу - стандартная управляющая конструкция если/иначе.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это не фриланс биржа

Answer (score 1):

Ф-я main() не может быть вложенной в Search

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Search(int a[],const int n,const int key)
{
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if ( a[i] == key )
            return i;
    return -1;
}

void main ()
{
    // Делаем здесь все что надо, например вызываем вашу ф-ю
    int array[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    Search( array, 10, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2). задание

```
#include <iostream>

void primeNumbersInArray(const int* arr, int size, std::ostream& hout) {
   int i;
   for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
       if(arr[j] <= 1)
           continue;

       for(i = 2; (i*i) <= arr[j]; ++i){
           if((arr[j] % i) == 0){
                i = -1;
                break;
           }
       }

       if(i != -1)
           hout << arr[j] << ' ';
   }
}

int main(void){
   int  arr[] = { 1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 66, 88, 149, 151, 157 };
   primeNumbersInArray(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), std::cout);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну вы блин даете, судя по задачкам он только начинает программирование изучать, а вы ему уже ф-ю с возможностью переопределения потока вывода. Как он игтересно будет преподу объяснять "свое" решение задачи :)))